# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'startsWith') error while deploying lambda edge function

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront, aws-lambda-edge

In AWS I am configuring CloudFront with S3 Origin. The S3 is configured for Server-Side Encryption with Customer Master Keys (CMKs). Because of the coudfront issue with S3 with CMK encryption, we have to use Lambda@Edge  function as suggested in [this AWS Article](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/serving-sse-kms-encrypted-content-from-s3-using-cloudfront/)
The Node JS code below is copied from the article linked

```
    // Declare constants reqiured for the signature process
const crypto = require('crypto');
const emptyHash = 'e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855';
const signedHeadersGeneric = 'host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date;x-amz-security-token';
// CloudFront includes the x-amz-cf-id header in the signature for custom origins
const signedHeadersCustomOrigin = 'host;x-amz-cf-id;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date;x-amz-security-token';
// Retrieve the temporary IAM credentials of the function that were granted by
// the Lambda@Edge service based on the function permissions. In this solution, the function
// is given permissions to read from S3 and decrypt using the KMS key.
const { AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, AWS_SESSION_TOKEN } = process.env;

// Since the function is configured to be executed on origin request events, the handler
// is executed every time CloudFront needs to go back to the origin, which is S3 here.
exports.handler = async event => {

    // Retrieve the original request that CloudFront was going to send to S3
    const request = event.Records[0].cf.request;

    // The request object has different properties depending on the type of
    // origin that is being used. Account for that here.
    let originType = '';
    if (request.origin.hasOwnProperty('s3'))
        originType = 's3';
    else if (request.origin.hasOwnProperty('custom'))
        originType = 'custom';
    else
        throw("Unexpected origin type. Expected 's3' or 'custom'. Got: " + JSON.stringify(request.origin));

    // Create a JSON object with the fields that should be included in the Sigv4 request,
    // including the X-Amz-Cf-Id header that CloudFront adds to every request forwarded
    // upstream. This header is exposed to Lambda@Edge in the event object
    const sigv4Options = {
        method: request.method,
        path: request.origin[originType].path + request.uri,
        credentials: {
            accessKeyId: AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
            secretAccessKey: AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
            sessionToken: AWS_SESSION_TOKEN
        },
        host: request.headers['host'][0].value,
        xAmzCfId: event.Records[0].cf.config.requestId,
        originType: originType
    };

    // Compute the signature object that includes the following headers: X-Amz-Security-Token, Authorization,
    // X-Amz-Date, X-Amz-Content-Sha256, and X-Amz-Security-Token
    const signature = signV4(sigv4Options);

    // Finally, add the signature headers to the request before it is sent to S3
    for(var header in signature){
        request.headers[header.toLowerCase()] = [{
            key: header,
            value: signature[header].toString()
        }];
    }

    return request;
};


// Helper functions to sign the request using AWS Signature Version 4
// This helper only works for S3, using GET/HEAD requests, without query strings
// https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4_signing.html
function signV4(options) {
    // Infer the region from the host header
    const region = options.host.split('.')[2];
    // Create the canonical request
    const date = (new Date()).toISOString().replace(/[:-]|\.\d{3}/g, '');
    let canonicalHeaders = '';
    let signedHeaders = '';
    if (options.originType == 's3') {
        canonicalHeaders = ['host:'+options.host, 'x-amz-content-sha256:'+emptyHash, 'x-amz-date:'+date, 'x-amz-security-token:'+options.credentials.sessionToken].join('\n');
        signedHeaders = signedHeadersGeneric;
    } else {
        canonicalHeaders = ['host:'+options.host, 'x-amz-cf-id:'+options.xAmzCfId, 'x-amz-content-sha256:'+emptyHash, 'x-amz-date:'+date, 'x-amz-security-token:'+options.credentials.sessionToken].join('\n');
        signedHeaders = signedHeadersCustomOrigin;
    }
    const canonicalURI = encodeRfc3986(encodeURIComponent(decodeURIComponent(options.path).replace(/\+/g, ' ')).replace(/%2F/g, '/'));
    const canonicalRequest = [options.method, canonicalURI, '', canonicalHeaders + '\n', signedHeaders,emptyHash].join('\n');
    // Create string to sign
    const credentialScope = [date.slice(0, 8), region, 's3/aws4_request'].join('/');
    const stringToSign = ['AWS4-HMAC-SHA256', date, credentialScope, hash(canonicalRequest, 'hex')].join('\n');
    // Calculate the signature
    const signature = hmac(hmac(hmac(hmac(hmac('AWS4' + options.credentials.secretAccessKey, date.slice(0, 8)), region), "s3"), 'aws4_request'), stringToSign, 'hex');
    // Form the authorization header
    const authorizationHeader = ['AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=' + options.credentials.accessKeyId + '/' + credentialScope,'SignedHeaders=' + signedHeaders,'Signature=' + signature].join(', ');

    // return required headers for Sigv4 to be added to the request to S3
    return {
        'Authorization': authorizationHeader,
        'X-Amz-Content-Sha256' : emptyHash,
        'X-Amz-Date': date,
        'X-Amz-Security-Token': options.credentials.sessionToken
    };
}

function encodeRfc3986(urlEncodedStr) {
  return urlEncodedStr.replace(/[!'()*]/g, c => '%' + c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16).toUpperCase())
}

function hash(string, encoding) {
  return crypto.createHash('sha256').update(string, 'utf8').digest(encoding)
}

function hmac(key, string, encoding) {
  return crypto.createHmac('sha256', key).update(string, 'utf8').digest(encoding)
}
```

However when I try to deploy the lambda@edge function with the suggested Node JS code it throws error `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'startsWith')`

What could be the issue here
[image]

Comment: I am also having this issue, did you ever figure it out?

Comment: I had this same problem. Deleting the first character in the distribution name (`a`) and then manually re-typing it caused validation to trigger, and then I was able to submit the form.

Comment: Correction: I toggled "CloudFront event" from "Origin Request" to "Origin Response", then back to "Origin Request" and this is what allowed me to finally submit the form.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Select in dropdown "viewer response" or "origin response" and after that return to "origin request".

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Andriy was right! this clearly looks like a AWS management console ui issue. Straight away if we select origin request from dropdown, and hit deploy. It throws the above mentioned error, but after selecting any other option from the dropdown and selecting origin request, then hitting deploy will resolve the issue.

Comment: as of now this is still not fixed, some one from AWS needs to look into this